# Ubuntu 12.10 No sound from headphone on iMac

Tags: 12.10, sound, headphones

I get sound from speakers but when I put headphones no sound coming. From system sound settings I check, and it is not muted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked alsamixer? Just open up a terminal and type "alsamixer" then check for "Auto-Mute Mode". If it's enabled, you'll need to disable it.

http://www.tutonics.com/2012/10/fix-no-sound-turn-off-auto-mute-in.html#.USDIwyXtzgg

Hopefully this helps. If not, the post from Ady in the comments section of the above link mentions to look for which channel you have set.

Alternatively, adjust the sound levels via alsamixer.

If the above doesn't work, then try http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2074897 which seems to be the problem you're having, but in reverse (headphones work, speakers do not)

Also, if all of the above doesn't work, there's pavucontrol for Pulseaudio. You may need to check the output settings. Ensure you're using Port: "Headphones"

Comment: Try "ps aux | grep pulseaudio". Any results would mean you've got pulseaudio. No results, try the below:

Taken from the Ubuntu wiki, "sudo apt-get install libasound2-plugins "pulseaudio-*" paman padevchooser paprefs pavucontrol pavumeter."

Comment: E: Package 'padevchooser' has no installation candidate